# How to extent SL4J to make it put logs into Kinesis stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-kinesis

The project has a few instances:
 - js frontend
 - js backend
 - java service

the log levels are:
 - debug
 - info
 - warning
 - error
 - fatal

I made the module for js instances that sends the logs to the kinesis to keep on track of my project.

How to do this in my java application?
Now the logging made with SL4J-simple in every class I have something like this:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainApplication.class);
```

How to add `fatal` log level and extend logger to write logs to Kinesis stream?

Comment: ,Did you got this resolved?

Comment: Yes. I used logback-classic.
I have extended the `AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent>`
and implemented the kinesis routine there.
now the app pushes every log message to kinesis.